# References(foreign key) in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have two models in sails

```
1. User_type
2. User
```

1. User_type Model:

   ```
   module.exports = {
   schema: true,
   connection: 'mongo',
   attributes: {

     user_type: {
     type: 'string',
     required: true,
     enum: ['superadmin', 'admin', 'follower']
   },    

   toJSON() {
   return this.toObject();
   }
   },

   beforeUpdate: (values, next) => next(),
   beforeCreate: (values, next) => next()
   };
   ```
2. User Model:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     schema: true,

     attributes: {


       fname: {
         type: 'string',
         required: true,
       },    

       user_login_type: {
         // This user_login_type should be having values from 
         // User_type Model with a reference to field 'user_type', that is
         // whatever values(superadmin', 'admin', 'follower') are in the
         // 'user_type' of collection(or model) 'User_type' should only be
         // allowed to enter here, and no else value
       },    


       toJSON() {
         return this.toObject();
       }
     },

     beforeUpdate: (values, next) => next(),
     beforeCreate: (values, next) => next()
   };
   ```

I referred to different docs, questions and answers, but am not getting the exact flow, how to do this in sails

Every help is really appreciable

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [associations](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations). You can create the reference using the `model` property:

```
...
user_login_type: {
    model: 'User_type'
},
...
```

Add `required: true` if you want to make it mandatory.

Note that the value of `user_login_type` won't be one of `'superadmin'`, `'admin'`, `'follower'`, but a reference to the associated model.